# Access classic asp application object with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm trying to access variables, previously set in application state object in global.asa, inside a server side javascript file.

In vbscript it's easy to access the application state object like so: `application("varname")`

When I try to do the same in javascript `application` variable is `undefined`.

What's the right way to access application state variable in classic asp using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to *JScript* means you are introducing case sensitivity;

```
Application("varname") = "foo";
```

Comment: well that was easy :)